# How can I customize the page coming after an event registration?

Tags: civievent, online-registration

we're having an event coming up and I've succeeded in setting up the event registration page in civicrm running on wordpress. I've already customized the registration confirmation e-mail, however, when it comes to the page that one is led to after finalizing the registration process, I have no idea how to customize it. Unfortunately, it contains multiple aspects I'd like to change.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards!

Comment: For a very versatile no-code solution, see this related answer: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/22720/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer the question myself: For WordPress, the solution is to access the following folder wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/ and change the template called 'ThankYou.tpl'

Hope this helps.

Best regards!
Jannis

Comment: Note that your changes would be lost after a civi upgrade, would recommend overriding this file in an extension.

Comment: This fix works if you want the same confirmation page for all events or you only have one event at at time. With the comment above from jitendrapurohit you can customize each event as well as withstand updates.

Answer (score 1):

In the Event Configuration > Online Registration you can edit three locations on the confirmation page--the Title, Intro, and Footer. You can add text or html in the "Thank You Screen" boxes and it will be displayed on the confirmation page.

If you need to edit more than this, see the above answer and comments.