# Redirect to page after Event Signup

Tags: civievent

We'd love to build custom 'Thank you' pages for our events using Drupal 7x., instead of using the WYSIWYG editor field on the CiviEvent page. Is there a way we can use Rules or CiviRules to immediately direct someone to a custom page after they sign up for an event? We can't use Webform CiviCRM because it does not offer price set support.

If you're interested - backstory: We want to have better social media integration, "share this event", contact us info, maps, etc. on this page. It seems somewhat limiting to use CiviCRM templates for creating this functionality when our page editing tools in Drupal are wonderful and easy.

Does https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.frontendpageoptions work on 4.7?

Drupal 7.x, CiviCRM 4.7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://civicrm.org/extensions/front-end-page-options is a likely solution and yes it works on 4.7 according to my list of which of our clients sites is using which extension ;-)

Comment: Is there any reason I don't see it in my 4.7 install list of available extensions? I know how to download it and install it, but just curious.

Comment: there are a number of steps extensions need to go through to get in that list - seems like this one hasn't been through all tasks